# Executing a stored procedure works from Management Studio and localhost but not when published to a server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am converting a website from Oracle to SQL Server 2016. The website is built in ASP.NET Framework 4 using Visual Studio 2015. The original developer made extensive use of Oracle packages for data manipulation and I have successfully converted everything to stored procedures and user-defined functions. I have successfully rewritten all of the web pages to use the new syntax. I can run the website on the localhost with no errors and am trying to get it to work on our development web server.

The problem: all stored procedures return the same error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'USP_My_Procedure', database 'WEB_DB', schema 'WEBDATA'

The user is a member of a Database role which is granted `DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE`, and `VIEW DEFINITION` permissions on the `WEBDATA` schema:

[image]

I am able to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE data directly from the webpages on the development server when stored procedures are not used. I am able to run the stored procedures from Management Studio when logged on using the application's SQL account. I just can't use the stored procedures to do the work from the website. Unfortunately, I don't have time to rewrite the entire application to eliminate the stored procedures.

Does anyone have any ideas of what to look for? Thank you.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but is it a linked server? What about RPC/RPC OUT settings?

Comment: No, not a linked server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your database connection string is using trusted security...

If you deployed an ASP.NET application to a development server you are likely using IIS.  If so, then you are likely using an Application Pool.  Verify the Application Pool identity has sufficient privileges on the database.  Performing a test includes connecting to the SQL Server as the security context the application pool identity is based on, then simply try to execute the failing stored procedure in a query window (using this security context).

To view Application Pools...

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager (A.K.A., inetmgr.exe)
- In left hand pane, expand server node and click to select 'Application Pools'
- In middle pane, click to select any application pool
- in right hand pane click to select 'Advanced Settings...'
- in section 'Process Model' notice value for 'Identity' (this value can be changed to a domain user account which can be assigned to SQL Server resources).

If you have more than one application pool the trick is to identify the one being used by your ASP.NET application...

Comment: I am new to IIS. Can you provide more details on how to do this?

Comment: I have never seen a connection to the database be done using the application pool. I don't even think that is possible. Typically you make your database connection from the website with a connection string, that is hopefully stored in the web.config file.

Comment: @SeanLange - (Assuming SQL Server ) If you are using trusted security then the connection string does not have any user id or password.  Here is a connection string example (using EF):  connectionString="data source=motoc_dev;initial catalog=motoc;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework".  In this case security context is derived from the process attempting to connect - for ASP.NET that is the app pool....

Comment: Until the applications are moved to user-acceptance testing, we keep the user name and password in the connection string.

Comment: @JAMMusic - Is the connection string identical between localhost development and your published development environments?

Comment: Yes. They are the exact same files, just moved to the server. The connection string is in the web.config.

Comment: Assuming the connection strings are the same and the problem persists, I would try to substitute the host name in the connection string for an IP address including port number to ensure the target system (and SQL Server Instance Name) is exactly what I am expecting.  I have experienced host file redirects in the past that had me turning in circles...

Comment: Wouldn't that affect all access to the database? I am able to select, insert, and delete data when I am not using the Stored Procedures.

Comment: @JAMMusic - Yes, the connection string is global and would effect all access to the database.  I guess I am grabbing at straws.  I assume the insert, updates, and deletes not only operate without error on the published web site, but also result in data changes you have explicitly verified in the target database - thus conclusively proving the connection string is accurate.

Comment: @JAMMusic - would you provide the connection string (mangling the userid and password for security purposes) for public scrutiny?

Comment: The connection string is: <add name="conSQL" connectionString="Data Source=SQL1\DEVELOP;Initial Catalog=WEB_DB;Integrated Security=True; USER ID=TestUser;PASSWORD=TestPassword;Application Name=MyApp;Persist Security Info=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: I believe that because you have Integrated Security set to true it is not using the User Id or the password.  Try this connection string instead..

Comment: <add name="conSQL" connectionString="Server=SQL1\DEVELOP;Database=WEB_DB;User Id=TestUser;Password=TestPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Maybe even just set Integrated Security to false and keep the rest of your connection string...

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures are executed. See the line in your permissions for EXECUTE? It is not granted to this user.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON USP_My_Procedure TO YourUser
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql

Comment: Yes it is granted. Notice there are two lines for EXECUTE. Follow the bottom one - Grantor: dbo with a check mark in the box. I would not be able to execute the procedure from Management Studio if it were not.

Comment: If you get that message it means one of two things. Either the execute permission was denied to the current user OR the execute permission was not granted. I would hope that you are not connecting in SSMS as the same user as your live site is using.

Comment: I logged into SSMS with the ID I am using on the website to test the permissions. Normally, I use my own login. I unchecked the box (using my own login) to see if it would give me the error and it did. I re-checked the box and the error is still occurring on the website.

Comment: So you are saying that using the same userid in SSMS the procedure is fine but fails with a permission issue when run from another location? That doesn't make sense. There has to be something else going on because both SSMS and your site are just clients making a connection and consuming the procedure. There has to be something different.

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't make any sense to me either - I am at a loss and don't know where else to look.

Comment: Is there a way to set up a log or trace or audit on the connection to see what groups/roles/users/gremlins are affecting access?